# ESC-символ, как записать?

Tags: c++

Мне надо посылать данные в принтер напрямую, используя функции WinAPi, в примере на C#, который нашел в сети, строка задается так (указываю сокращенно) :

```
string st4 = "\x1b*c6a600b0P";
```

Тут \x1b - это символ ESC.

Но мне надо написать тоже самое на Си (для простоты написал консольное приложение в Visual Studio), там объявляю строку так:

```
CStringW st4 = "\x1b*c6a600b0P";
```

Но в этом случае \x1b не воспринимается как символ ESC. 
Подскажите пожалуйста, как на Си написать символ ESC?

Comment: `CStringW` — это на Си? о_О

Comment: `\x1b` должно работать. These aren't the Droids your looking for.

Comment: Да, консольное приложение в VS..

Comment: В отладчике смотрю содержимое строки - в C# там вместо \x1b символ стрелочки, а вот в проекте С++ там \x1b

Comment: Ну, мало ли как отладчик показывает непечатные символы. Это его проблема.

Comment: Пасиб, буду проверять на принтере..

Comment: С CString такой же результат в отладчике : st4 L"\x1b*c6a600b0P" ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,ATL::StrTraitATL

Comment: А вам реально нужно широкая строка или узкая? (И кстати, классы, а тем более — шаблоны, это точно не Си.)

Comment: Да я и не знаю, какая нужна.. :) Нашел пример на C#, пытаюсь его перенести на Си.. Строка на решетке была определена так, как я выше написал. Пытаюсь по аналогии сделать на Си, правда компилятор ругается, ибо функция WritePrinter из WinApi в качестве указателя на буфер принимает LPVOID, поэтому приходится делать так:

Comment: CStringW str = L"unicode";
    int bytelen = 2 * str.GetLength();
    LPBYTE pByte = new BYTE[bytelen];
    memcpy(pByte, str, bytelen);
    DWORD count = bytelen;
    WritePrinter(printerName, pByte, count, &dwBytesWritten);

Comment: Попробуйте неюникодную строку, если ваш старый код работал с ней. // Хотя стоп. В C# строки юникодные. Отставить, возвращаемся к юникодным строкам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы использовать `WinApi`шные функции с Ansi-строками нужно или явно вызывать версию с суффиксом `A`, либо отключить в опциях проекта Unicode, для этого установить опцию `Configuration Properties - General - Character Set` в значение `Not Set`.

После этого задать правильно строковый литерал:

```
const char* str = "\x1b*c6a600b0P";
```

И передать его нужной апишной функции.

То, что отладчики C++ и C# по-разному отображают строку - это совершенно не важно и не стоит на этом акцентировать внимание. Главное, чтобы передавались нужные данные реальному потребителю (принтеру).

Answer (score 2):

Объекты для строк вам, вполне вероятно, не нужны. И тогда проблема решается так:

```
unsigned char buffer[] = "\x1b*c6a600b0P";
```

Comment: Попробовал - в отладчике все равно \x1b..

Comment: @MaratG я тоже попробовал в отладчике и в памяти находится байт 0x1B.

Comment: Владимир, посмотрел еще раз, у меня тоже нулевой байт 0x1B. Видимо, отладчик  в проекте на C# первый символ строки показывает стрелочкой (которая, как я понимаю, и означает символ ESC). А в проекте консольного приложения С++ в отладчике отображается иначе..

Comment: @MaratG не нужно смотреть символы, смотрите значения байтов. Благо именно эти байты вы и будете слать.

Comment: Да, я уже понял, спасибо. Но тогда вопрос : если в C# переменная объявлена как string str = "\x1b*c6a600b0P"; то чтобы в отладчике посмотреть содержимое байтов, надо воспользоваться функцией c_str ()?

Comment: Не знаю, я на .NET не пишу.